# Определить тип объекта и инициализировать им обобщенный класс

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Вопрос касается внедрения завиимостей в ASP.Net Core
Необходимо внедрить два сервиса.

Сервис №1:

```
public interface IExchange
{
   Task<ExchangeCallbackMessage> GetAddressAsync(CallParams callParams);
}

public class PoloExchange : IExchange
{
   public PoloExchange(ConfigureContext context)
   {
      //initialize
   }

   public async Task<ExchangeCallbackMessage> GetAddressAsync(CallParams callParams)
   {
      //implement
   }
}
```

Метод расширения с помощью которого я добавлю этот сервис в коллекцию сервисов

```
public static void AddExchanges(this IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddSingleton<IExchange, PoloExchange>();
}
```

Сервис №2(он будет типизироваться вариантами сервиса №1):

```
public class ExchangePipeline<T> where T : class, IExchange
{

    internal readonly T exchangeClient;
    private Queue<Call<T>> Processor { get; set; }
    public event ExchangeHandler Callback;

    public void CallbackAction(ExchangeCallbackMessage callbackMessage)
        => Callback?.Invoke(callbackMessage);

    public ExchangePipeline(T exchange)
    {
        exchangeClient = exchange;
        Processor = new Queue<Call<T>>();

        var tm = new TimerCallback(TactAction);
        var timer = new Timer(tm, new object(), 0, 167);
    }

    public void TactAction(object obj)
    {
        //var processor = obj as Queue<Call<T>>;
        while (true)
        {
            if (Processor.Count != 0)
            {
                CallbackAction(Processor.Dequeue().Execute(exchangeClient));
            }
            else continue;
        }
    }

    public async Task AddCallAsync(Call<T> call)
        => await Task.Run(() => Processor.Enqueue(call));
}
```

Метод расширения для добавления Срвиса №2 хотел реализовать следующим образом (пройтись по коллекции сервисов взять все варианты сервисов №1, на их основе создать типизированные сервисы №2 и добавить в коллекцию)

```
public static void AddPipelines(this IServiceCollection services)
{
  foreach (var service in services)
    {
       //var serviseType = service.GetType();
       if (service.GetType() is IExchange) services.AddSingleton<ExchangePipeline<service.GetType()>>();
    }                
}
```

но компилятор ругается, мол используйте конкретный тип обобщения.

Можно, конечно, добавить каждый в ручную

```
services.AddSingleton<ExchangePipeline<PoloExchange>>();
services.AddSingleton<ExchangePipeline<KunaExchange>>();
services.AddSingleton<ExchangePipeline<LiveExchange>>();
```

но так не хочется.

Ну и в итоге это все регистрируем в `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddExchanges();
   services.AddPipelines();
}
```

Comment: Набросай структуру классов. Выложи её, чтобы на её основе можно было искать решение. То есть, чтобы что-то придумать, нужно хотя бы консольное приложение со структурой классов, которое компилируется и на его основе расскомментировав некоторые строки можно увидеть твою конкретноую проблему. Здесь же слишком много неизвестных. Я уверен, что найти решение можно. Хотя добавление вручную, кстати, так и нужно делать. То есть, решение вряд ли будет в виде обобщений, как ты хотел.

Comment: @CasperSC, отредактировал вопрос. Если буду добавлять вручную, то со временем оба метода разростуться, а так бы я типа по SOLID добавлял бы в одном месте -> `AddExchanges(this IServiceCollection services)` и `AddPipelines(this IServiceCollection services)` выглядел простенько.

Comment: Вы уверены что вам нужен именно генерик тип для `ExchangePipeline`? Просто судя по декларации вы собираетесь использовать в нем только классы реализующие интерфейс. А раз так, то по чему просто не использовать только интерфейс в `ExchangePipeline` как обычное поле?

Comment: И еще не понятно на какой имено `IExchange` будет ссылатся `ExchangePipeline`. На синголтана из колекции или он будет свою создавать?

Comment: @Vasek по задумке количесво `ExchangePipeline` должно соответствовать количеству реализаций 'IExchange'.  Задача каждого запустить внутри себя тактовый механизм частота коорого будет зависеть от конкретного 'IExchange' (см. вопрос я туда закинул примерную реализацию `ExchangePipeline`)

Answer (score 0):

1. Я в ASP нуб так что, то что я напишу может бутет не очень верно с точки зрения его идеологии.
2. Компилятор ругается потому что все что внутри `<>` должно вычисляться на стадии компиляции. `object.GetType()` Это выражения времени выполнения.
3. Если я все правильно понял, то `ExchangePipeline` совсем не нужно делать генериком, но отвечу по генерику.

**Типы:**

```
public interface IExchange
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class ExchangeImpl1 : IExchange
{
    public ExchangeImpl1()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class ExchangeImpl2 : IExchange
{
    public ExchangeImpl2()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class ExchangePipeline<T> where T : class, IExchange
{
    T _exchangeClient;

    public ExchangePipeline(T exchangeClient)
    {
        _exchangeClient = exchangeClient;
    }

    public void DoSomeWork()
    {
        _exchangeClient.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

**Вариант решения №1(Примерно как в вопросе):**

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions1
{
    public static void AddExchanges(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IExchange, ExchangeImpl1>();
        services.AddSingleton<IExchange, ExchangeImpl2>();
    }

    public static void AddPipelines(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var exchangesInstances = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetServices<IExchange>();
        foreach (object exchangeInstance in exchangesInstances) {
            AddPipelineSingleton(services, exchangeInstance.GetType(), exchangeInstance);
        }
    }

    private static void AddPipelineSingleton(IServiceCollection services, Type exchangeType, object exchangeInstance)
    {
        var pipelineTypeProtype = typeof(ExchangePipeline<>);
        var pipelineTypeGenerics = new Type[] { exchangeType };
        var pipelineType = pipelineTypeProtype.MakeGenericType(pipelineTypeGenerics);

        var pipelineInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(pipelineType, exchangeInstance);
        services.AddSingleton(pipelineType, pipelineInstance);
    }
}
```

**Вариант решения №2(Как можно просто и коротко решить задачу):**

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions2
{
    public static void AddExchanges(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        AddExchangeSingleton(services, new ExchangeImpl1());
        AddExchangeSingleton(services, new ExchangeImpl2());
    }

    private static void AddExchangeSingleton<T>(IServiceCollection services, T exchange) where T : class, IExchange
    {
        services.AddSingleton<T>(exchange);
        // или так services.AddSingleton<IExchange>(exchange);
        services.AddSingleton<ExchangePipeline<T>>(new ExchangePipeline<T>(exchange));
    }
}
```